# Share the eclipse search result/ query

Tags: eclipse, search

I just want to know if the search result in eclipse search view can be shared with fellow team mate as it is. 
I perform a search and delete few unwanted entries and then send it to him/ her
The other person shall be able to view it exactly same manner in the search view.
Is there a way to do this?
The will be very helpful for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be looking at the Mylyn project (http://eclipse.org/mylyn).

This project allows you to create tasks and send them to co-workers through a task repository (such as bugzilla, jira, or most major issue trackers).  Attached to these tasks are "contexts", which associate code elements (methods, fields, classes, etc) with the task.

Here is what you would need to do:

1. Install mylyn (you and all co-workers)
2. Install the proper connector for your issue tracker (most major issue trackers have one).  If you are not using an issue tracker, then you can still import and export tasks as files, but it is less easy to do, and I'd recommend using an issue tracker anyway.
3. Now add the task repository to your Eclipse.  This is the way that mylyn speaks to your issue tracker.  It allows you to create issues, bug reports, tasks, etc, from within Eclipse.

With this set up, you can now create a task associated with a task repository and activate it.  You can add the desired program elements to your task by right clicking -> Mark as Landmark.

Once you have your task context complete, you can then attach the context to the remote repository (essentially attaching a zip file to the issue in your issue tracker).  Other users can then retrieve the context and immediately start working with the context that you created.

It is really a great way to work when you need to share information about specific features in the code to other people on the project.

Comment: Although not fully wht i imagined, this seems useful enough. Thanks andrew i will install this and try to push it in my team

Comment: Mylyn is a lot more flexible than what you are looking for above, but you are right in that it does not directly do what you are asking for with the search results.

Comment: Started using it and even my team mates seem to be happy to use it . Thanks again andrew. Except for the not so intuitive UI, this is useful plug in